# Luke 23:43 — Should the word “today” be interpreted literally in that 24-hour days continue after death?

Tags: luke, resurrection

> 43 And he said to him, “Truly, I say to you, today you will be with me in paradise. Luke 23:43

Both Jesus and the criminal died on the same day. Because they were reunited in paradise after death, should the word “today” be understood as a 24-hour day that extended into paradise, or, should the word “today” be understood as a future, unspecified time? The answer should not contradict John 20:17, where after the resurrection, Jesus had not yet ascended to his Father. This question can be closed. The answer can be found here: [Where was Jesus after he stopped breathing on the Cross until he came out of the tomb?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/52332/where-was-jesus-after-he-stopped-breathing-on-the-cross-until-he-came-out-of-the/52340#52340)

Comment: By moving the 'translators' comma, Truly, I say to you today, you will be with me in paradise', we get the intended meaning - yes?

Comment: @user48152 agreed. I'm asking because the original punctuation is unknown. Jesus spoke figuratively often. The range of meaning for the word "today" can mean a 24 hour day to a limited period of time. Because the context is after death, I'm interested in hearing different answers.

Comment: @NigelJ Not a duplicate. My question deals with the meaning of the word "today." Thanks

Comment: If Jesus perceived a day with God’s Eyes, then “today” to Him might equal 1000-years. [Psalm 90:4] “כִּ֚י אֶ֪לֶף שָׁנִ֡ים בְּֽעֵינֶ֗יךָ כְּי֣וֹם” For a thousand years in Your Eyes is like a day.

Comment: This also answers the question : https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/a/52629/21426

Comment: @NigelJ It does not answer how the word "today" should be interpreted in Luke 23:43.

Comment: Does this answer your question?  https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/52332/where-was-jesus-after-he-stopped-breathing-on-the-cross-until-he-came-out-of-the/52340#52340

Comment: @Dottard Your answer was on point. It covered the common Hebrew idiom for today which is related to this question. I gave you points for you answer. Should this question  be closed or do you want to answer it?

Comment: @Dottard Thanks for your answer. I'll try to close it.

Comment: @Dottard I don't know how to close it.

Comment: @Dottard No, the one that does is your answer: https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/a/52340/2452

Comment: @JesusSaves - OK thanks.